# Can select() be used with blocking sockets?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, network-programming

I want to use `select()` to monitor if a socket has data to be read, but I do not want to use non-blocking sockets. So can `select()` be used with blocking sockets?

I am using Windows.

Comment: lol how is this question "unclear"? you people are strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is *the entire point* of `select`.

It watches for activity on sockets that would block if you tried to `read` from them without knowing that data were there. Most importantly, it can watch for activity on *multiple* sockets, which you couldn't do without `select` on a blocking socket unless you had each socket handled in a separate thread. Also importantly, it tells you when a socket is ready for reading *and/or* for writing; simply invoking either `read` or `write` can't do that.

The behaviour of `select` is even [documented](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) in these terms:

> `select()` and `pselect()` allow a program to monitor multiple file descriptors, waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become "ready" for some class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible). **A file descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform the corresponding I/O operation (e.g., `read(2)`) without blocking.**

Of course, you can also use it with non-blocking sockets, because otherwise in order to "wait" for activity you'd have to come up with a `read`-`sleep`-`read`-`sleep`-… loop and that's suboptimal for a few reasons.